# Python: Open all files that do not match a pattern

Tags: python, glob

I'm trying to open all the files in a directory that do not match a pattern. The directory will have files in it like `x_0192910`, `y_18329123` and `z_00000000`; I want to open all the files that do not end in '`00000000`', eight zeroes. I've been trying to use `glob.glob()`, but I can't get the regex right. I've tried things like `*^0{8,8}` and `*[!0]`, but I'm not sure about how to construct the correct expression.

So to summarise, I just need something like `glob.glob('not *_00000000')`. Can anyone help?

Comment: regex `^(?!.*?0{8}$).+$`

Comment: Note that glob patterns are _not_ regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about filtering the list that `glob` returns? Something like:

```
for e in glob.glob('*'):
    if e[-9:] == "_00000000":
        continue
    # Do whatever you like
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use endswith and filter:

```
import glob
for i in filter(lambda x:not x.endswith('_00000000'), glob.glob('*.*')):
    print i
```

You can also use list comprehension:

```
import glob
for i in [e for e in glob.glob('*.*') if not e.endswith('_00000000')]:
    print i
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to write that string as `'_'+8*'0'`; it's not much shorter, but it's easier to see that there are exactly eight zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Globs are fundamentally different from regular expressions.

The closest you can get is probably "does not have a '0' in the last 8 characters". If that is not good enough, you will simply have to get the full list and filter using `endswith`.

FWIW, the glob pattern rules are:

```
* match 0 or more "any character"
? match exactly one "any character"
[...] match character range
[!...] negated character range (all but the chars in the range
```